# Iterating over a jsonlike object

Tags: react-native

I am pretty new to java script (and react/react-native in general), i received an object threw an API and converted the response to JSON,
the object is formatted like this:

```
{name1: {…}, name2: {…}, name3: {…}, name4: {…},...}
```

when each `{...}` contains `"data": number`
how can i iterate over all possible results and display (preferably in a flatlist)
the info like this `name (i)->number (i)`

i don't imagine it being much help but this is what i have so far

```
 return(
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.res}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.currentVotes}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={({id}) => id}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer i came up with, its not prefect but it works

```
var resScreen = []
res=this.state.res
for(a in res){
  resScreen.push(
    <View>
      <Text>{a},{this.state.res[a].currentVotes}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
return resScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through Objects you need to get an array of all keys of that Object and finally iterate from that array.

like this, you can get all keys using single line

```
let data = {name1: {…}, name2: {…}, name3: {…}, name4: {…},...};
let keys = Object.keys(data);
```

and to iterate through array simply use map function,

```
keys.map(item=>
<View>
  <Text>{data[item]}</Text>
</View> 
)
```